# Dynamic SQL Select

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

So I was wondering how I can do this, I am using SQL Server Compact and need to do a specific thing.

I need to append a string to an int, resulting in a string if a column is not equal to a value

For example lets say I have this query here

```
SELECT id, Auto FROM example
```

Right now to get what I want I will have to do this select and then resolve it after like so

```
string id = dr["id"].ToString() + 
                dr["Auto"].ToString().IsNotNullOrWhitespace() 
                    ? " (Auto)" : "");
```

How can I get the same result in SQL? AS something like this

```
SELECT id ..... as id FROM example
```

(Auto is defined as`INT NULL`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but you can try the following

```
SELECT (
        case id
             WHEN 1 
                  THEN id + ' (Auto)' 
             ELSE id END) as id 
FROM example
```